# WPF DataBind to class in another project

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I searched before posting this question and although there are similar questions I am still stuck with the error: The tag 'Customers' does not exist in XML namespace 'BusinessObjects'.

```
namespace BusinessObjects
{
public class Customers
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    }

    ObservableCollection<string> CustomerIds { get; set; }

    public Customers()
    {
        // populate CustomerIds
    }
}
}
```

My XAML

```
    <UserControl xmlns:BusObj="BusinessObjects">
        <UserControl.DataContext>
            <BusObj:Customers />
        </UserControl.DataContext>

        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerIds}"/>
    </UserControl>
```

Comment: Post your `xmlns` line for `BusObj`. I believe you need to add the `;assembly=` to the end of it.

Comment: @clcto Looks like its locally defined, and missing the assembly

Comment: BusinessObjects is referenced in the project and I set using BusinessObjects as a test in the code behind where it resolves without error. The error suggests to me that it can find BusinessObjects but for some reason can't find the Customers class within the BusinessObjects namespace. Am I reading that correctly?

Comment: @FSL_AU when you define the `BusObj` XML namespace, you need to provide the assembly that it is part of if it is not part of the same assembly. For example `xmlns:BusObj="clr-namespace:BusinessObjects;assembly=BusinessObjectAssembly"` where `BusinessObjectAssembly` is the project name.  What is the project name that contains the C# code you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are referencing classes defined in a different assembly, you must give the assembly name when you declare the XML Namespace:

```
<UserControl xmlns:BusObj="clr-namespace:BusinessObjects;assembly=AssemblyName">
```

where `AssemblyName` is the name of the assembly, which is generally just the name of the project that contains the code.

Comment: Thank you @clcto. That did the trick. Can you tell me why it requires both the namespace and the assembly name? I would have thought the namespace alone would have been sufficient given the assembly is referenced in the project.

Comment: @FSL_AU that is an implementation detail that I do not know.